# How to set text alignment while using flalign?

Tags: flalign

I am trying to write equations using flalign and I have text in my equations on the left. What I want is that the text on the left be left aligned however it is currently aligning itself to where the words end leaving blank space on the left hand side in cases where the words are smaller. Below is the code that I am working with

```
\begin{flalign}
    && \theta_{0}(t) &= K_{v}\int\limits_0^t e_{0}(\lambda)d\lambda&\\ 
    \text{On differentiating} && \Dot{\theta}_{0}(t) &= K_{v}e_{0}(t)&\\
    \text{On transforming} && s\theta_{0}(s) &= K_{v}E_{0}(S)&\\
\end{flalign}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE.

Comment: `flalign` has three alignment columùns, hence it requires *five* ampersands.

Answer (score 3):

Maybe this is a job for `witharrows`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{witharrows}
\newcommand{\diff}{\mathop{}\!\mathrm{d}}
\begin{document}
\begin{DispWithArrows}[displaystyle,fleqn]
\theta_{0}(t) &= K_{v}\int\limits_0^t e_{0}(\lambda)\diff\lambda
\Arrow{\text{On differentiating}}\\ 
    \Dot{\theta}_{0}(t) &= K_{v}e_{0}(t)
\Arrow{\text{On transforming}}\\    
     s\theta_{0}(s) &= K_{v}E_{0}(S)\vphantom{\int\limits_0^t}
\end{DispWithArrows}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Something like this?

[image]

```
\documentclass{article} % or some other suitable document class
\usepackage{amsmath}    % for 'flalign' env.
\begin{document}
\begin{flalign}
&                          & \theta_{0}(t)       &= K_{v}\int_0^t\!e_{0}(\lambda)\,d\lambda &\\ 
&\text{On differentiating} & \Dot{\theta}_{0}(t) &= K_{v}e_{0}(t) &\\
&\text{On transforming  }  & s\theta_{0}(s)      &= K_{v}E_{0}(S) &
\end{flalign}
\end{document}
```

---

I actually think that an `alignat` environment may be more suitable to the job than the `flalign` environment is.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article} % or some other suitable document class
\usepackage{amsmath}    % for 'alignat' env.
\begin{document}
\begin{alignat}{3}
&            && \hspace{2cm} & \theta_{0}(t)       &= K_{v}\int_0^t\!e_{0}(\lambda)\,d\lambda\\ 
&\text{On differentiating}&& & \Dot{\theta}_{0}(t) &= K_{v}e_{0}(t) \\
&\text{On transforming}   && & s\theta_{0}(s)      &= K_{v}E_{0}(S) 
\end{alignat}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2):

You have to insert the correct number of & in the right place. I suggest another solution, with a simpler code, using the `fleqn` environment from `nccmath`, and `alignat`, which will give you full control on the spacing the text and the equations:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{nccmath, mathtools}
\usepackage{showframe} 
\usepackage{amssymb}

\begin{document}

\begin{flalign}
    && \theta_{0}(t) &= K_{v}\int\limits_0^t e_{0}(\lambda)d\lambda&\\
     & \text{On differentiating} & \Dot{\theta}_{0}(t) &= K_{v}e_{0}(t)&\\
    & \text{On transforming} & s\theta_{0}(s) &= K_{v}E_{0}(S)&\\
\end{flalign}

\begin{fleqn}
\begin{alignat}{2}
    && \theta_{0}(t) &= K_{v}\int\limits_0^t e_{0}(\lambda)d\lambda \\
     & \text{On differentiating} &\hspace{4em} \Dot{\theta}_{0}(t) &= K_{v}e_{0}\\
    & \text{On transforming} & s\theta_{0}(s) &= K_{v}E_{0}(S)
\end{alignat}
\end{fleqn}

\end{document}
```

[image]